# How to put Math.round into a function and making user input int limited?

Tags: javascript, html

this is the code:

```
<script>
function doAll(x) {

}
</script>

<input type="number" oninput="this.value = Math.round(this.value);doAll(this.value);">
```

I would like to put the code:

```
this.value = Math.round(this.value);
```

into function. so it will be:

```
<input type="number" oninput="doAll(this.value);">
```

what I did:

```
<script>
function doAll(x) {
    x = Math.round(x);
}
</script>

<input type="number" oninput="doAll(this.value);">
```

function's calc works. but after this, user's input no longer int limited.
how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `this.value` anymore, you're setting a copied value (`x`). Try the following:

```js
function doAll(e) {
    x = Math.round(e.value);
    e.value = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="doAll(this);">
```

Comment: good idea, I need to set the value. but this.value = x; not working.

Comment: My bad, I updated the answer for a fully working sample.

Comment: I just tried setting id and using jquery. but yours is better. thank you. :)